# How to change font-family and other sass variables in balmui with vue 2

Tags: webpack, sass, vuejs2, balmui

I'm new to **BalmUI**. I was reading the [docs](https://v8.material.balmjs.com/#/guide/advanced) about **Use Sass** and how we could change the **sass variables** in the components of this framework. According to that docs, I created **app** and **config** folders in the root directory of my vue 2 project. I pasted the codes mentioned in **balmrc.js** file. Also in the `app/styles/global/_vendor.scss` file, I added the following codes:

```
@use '@material/typography/typography' with (
  $font-family: string.unquote('Roboto, sans-serif'),
);

@use 'balm-ui/dist/balm-ui';
```

I don't know how could I address the fonts that are located in my local directory (for example in `public/fonts/font-name.ttf`) to this `_vendor.scss` file.

But the bigger problem is that after adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/styles/main.css" />` (according to the docs) to my `public/index.html` file, I get this error in my cmd prompt:

[image: error related to BalmUI]

That error may happen because there is not such a file or directory. Or may some additional configurations is needed to my project. But I think that "BalmUI" must create that files and add custom changes to SASS variables to that.

Here are the codes in my "main.js" and "vue.config.js" files:

> main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import BalmUI from 'balm-ui'; // Official Google Material Components
import BalmUIPlus from 'balm-ui-plus'; // BalmJS Team Material Components
import 'balm-ui-css';

Vue.use(BalmUI); // Mandatory
Vue.use(BalmUIPlus); // Optional

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

> vue.config.js:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  // NOTE: set alias via `configureWebpack` or `chainWebpack`
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'balm-ui-plus': 'balm-ui/dist/balm-ui-plus.js',
        'balm-ui-css': 'balm-ui/dist/balm-ui.css'
      }
    }
  }
  // chainWebpack: (config) => {
  //   config.resolve.alias
  //     .set('balm-ui-plus', 'balm-ui/dist/balm-ui-plus.js')
  //     .set('balm-ui-css', 'balm-ui/dist/balm-ui.css');
  // }
})
```

I don't know a lot about **Webpack**. I just created a new vue project and added "BalmUI" to it. I want to change SASS variables mentioned in different components in my project to customize the style (for example changing `font-family`). I want from any developer that could help me to solve this problem, post an answer to this question.